# What type of derailleur hanger is this? Where can I buy it?

Tags: derailleur-hanger

I would like to replace my bike's derailleur hanger since it broke accidentally.
I've been struggling to find the type of derailleur hanger on the internet, so any help identifying it and where to buy it is very welcome.
Here are pictures of the rear wheel showing the derailleur hanger:
[image: Rear wheel with derailleur hanger]
[image: Rear derailleur hanger]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  One of those bikes isn't yours, since they're not the same colour.  (It's not even clear they're the same make or using the same components.)  Can you include more details about the components on your bike?  I can see the derailleur is a Shimano Tourney, but that's a fairly broad product line, and it doesn't look an exact match to any current models.

Comment: I'm guessing that the 2nd picture is the actual bike in question, as opposed to the "random internet image of something similar" in the 1st image. I've gotta say, that doesn't look particularly broken to me. Maybe provide an actual picture of the actual broken part

Comment: Please add a clean and clear photo of your broken hanger, laid out like it would be if not broken.  Use [edit] to add to your post.  Also please quote the manufacturer of your bike frame - I see "Red Peak" and "Star Cat" but that doesn't google up any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hanger 485 at derailleurhanger.com looks like a possibility.
https://derailleurhanger.com/product/derailleur-hanger-485/
But without seeing the frame with the hanger removed it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Was just about to say the same one, which I think is also the same as Wheels Mfg 339

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I was looking for! I just received this hanger from derailleurhanger.com and it's a perfect match! Thanks a lot!